# In collisions between a body and a surface, along what direction is momentum conserved?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision

> [image: 1]

In which direction should the momentum be conserved? I am getting confused at deciding that. I know momentum will be conserved in the direction where no external force is acting on the system.

Comment: Hi Tanisha, warm welcome to physics stack exchange. The type of question you've posted here is not apt for the site. [see here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange#:~:text=As%20a%20general%20rule%2C%20we,specific%20conceptual%20physics%20questions%20answered.). If you want to convert the problem in this question to one which is askable on this site, try to extract what 'concept' is making you stuck from solving this question, and try ask a question specifically about that, maybe adding in this problem for context.

Comment: "Though {\displaystyle C_{R}}C_{R} does not explicitly depend on the masses of the objects, it is important to note that the final velocities are mass-dependent. For two- and three-dimensional collisions of rigid bodies, the velocities used are the components perpendicular to the tangent line/plane at the point of contact, i.e. along the line of impact." [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution#Speeds_after_impact)

Comment: just one question, Why is it that the system in consideration here is the ball without the wegde. If the system is ball+wedge, the impulse force along the nomral becomes internal. Is it because there is some impulse force from the support of the wedge?

Comment: You are thinking in the right lines, both bodies face and equal and opposite force along the impact line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force acting on the body at the moment of impact is a normal force perpendicular to the inclined plane. Therefore momentum *parallel* to the inclined plane is conserved.

Comment: But what about the force of gravity? Isn't a component of gravity always there(as an external force) along the incline?

Comment: @TanishaDaharwal Gravity is not an impulsive force. In collisions, the key forces to consider are only the impulsive ones. Resnick Halliday had a good discussion on this iirc

Answer (score 0):

To see things clearly, I would suggest you to change your reference frame,  rotate the system such that you would align the inclined surface with ground. Then the problem is very simple. After you find the angles (the vectors make with ground (which is inclined plane after rotation)) the components of the incoming and outgoing velocity will switch but the magnitude will remain same. So the answer will again be 3 m/s.

Comment: You are assuming that the collision is perfectly elastic, so the kinetic energy of the body after the collision is the same as it was before. But we are not told that the collision is elastic. In fact, since the angle between the body’s velocity and the plane changes in the collision, we know that the collision is *not* perfectly elastic.

Comment: Yeah since I did not see any friction or so, I assumed that the collision is elastic. Since angles differ then the collision will be inelastic. But I still do not understand where does the excess energy goes, it is just a single point contact and there is no motion in the inclined plane after collision.